# Making app free and giving all in-app-purchases free to people who already paid

Tags: android

I've got an app in Google Play store, which was paid. Since there was a little interest, I've made it free. Now I come with idea of paid extensions to it (new levels), but I would like to give it for free for those, who already paid.

So, my idea is generally to:

1. get info about did user paid for app?
2. somehow give previous users all in-app purchases automatically ?

Question is, I cannot find a good info about it in documentation, so can you help?

For the first one I was thinking about this: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html - but it looks that it won't return info for main product, just for all paid options.

For the second one, is it possible to give in-app purchase for free to users who paid (app is free from a month, so I need to filter users somehow...)?